# Mock/patch result of pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read.parquet

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to mock dataframe read by SparkSession.read.parquet like other functions(e.g. os.getcwd()), but decorator returns attribute error.
Do you know how to mock return value of read.parquet?

```
import os
from spark.sql import SparkSession
from unittest.mock import patch
import pyspark

@patch('os.getcwd')
def test_works(cwd_mock):
    cwd_mock.return_value = 'foo'
    assert os.getcwd() == 'foo'

@patch('pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read.parquet')
def test_not_works(parquet_mock):
    spark:SparkSession = generate_spark_session() # function is defined separately
    parquet_mock.return_value = df # df is created separately
    assert spark.read_parquet('foo/bar') == df
```

Error message
[image: error message]

Comment: It seems the patched ``pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read`` has no attribute ``parquet``. Did you look at the documentation about the ``read`` property? Finally, are you sure the ``spark.read_parquet`` actually uses ``pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read.parquet``?